# Run Integration Tests Against Multiple Target Platforms

Tags: maven, tycho

I'm currently tasked with switching one of our applications from Eclipse 3.7 and 4.5. Sadly nobody had anticipated how screwed up the new framework is, which is why the others applications will stay at 3.7 for now. Now comes the tricky part: to speed up the bug finding process, I want to test our common plug-ins against 4.5 (but they still need to test against 3.7 of course).

[This thread](http://tycho-user.eclipse.narkive.com/K8c4veg0/run-integration-tests-against-multiple-target-platforms) suggests it might be possible with the help `maven-invoker-plugin`, but its 2 years old and this is a really common use case, so there might be something better now.

I can't find anything on how to make the `maven-invoker-plugin` work with Tycho. And the `tycho-surefire-plugin` doesn't seem to have any option to change the target platform.

Just in case, I'm talking about this target platform (which doesn't seem to be supported / used outside the documentation):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
        <target>
            <artifact>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.acme.project</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>platform</classifier>
            </artifact>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So how do I test my integration tests against multiple target platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to do this during a single build, i.e., in a single reactor? If not, you can simply switch target platforms based on a system property passed to Maven, e.g., by a [Jenkins/Hudson matrix build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project):

```
<target>
  <artifact>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${targetPlatform}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>platform</classifier>
  </artifact>
</target>
```

Just remember to configure a default for your `targetPlatform` property under `project/properties`, so builds without `-DtargetPlatform=...` being set won’t fail.

(At Eclipse Code Recommenders, we use this setup to regularly [test against 6 different Eclipse releases](https://hudson.eclipse.org/recommenders/job/org.eclipse.recommenders-master/).)

Answer (score 0):

I also found a way to run the tests in the same reactor.

I create a copy of the test fragment without all the test classes and added the E4 target platform via `target-platform-configuration`. Then I used this code to copy the classes and *fragment.xml* to the new module:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-classes</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/it-classes</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../${original-test-project}/src</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-fragment</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../${original-test-project}/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>fragment.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Finally the *build.properties* must have the line `source.. = target/it-classes/`so that the Maven build can compile the copied classes and run them normally.